# How to pass JSON object with code, message and list?

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

In my rest web API, If a user sends a request with student-id, in response, API sends a message, code, and list of subjects created by the student with that id. 
how to send a response with all these details

I have created one JSON object with key-value pairs. and return JSON object as response.

```java
public class SubjectResources {

  SubjectService subjectService = new SubjectService();

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public List<Subject> getSubjectList(@QueryParam("user_id") long user_id) {

  List<Subject> sub = subjectService.getAllSubejcts(user_id);//checked and List sub has all details.

  JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

  json.put("code", 200);
  json.put("message", "Success");
  json.put("subject", sub);`

  return json;
}
```

**Expected result:** 
Format of response should be :

```
{ 
   "code":200, 
   "message":"Success", 
   "subjects":
         {
            "id":"1", 
            "name":"Maths", 
            "total_chapters":"3", 
            "total_assignments":"3"
          },
        {
            "id":"2", 
            "name":"Maths2", 
            "total_chapters":"4", 
            "total_assignments":"5"
          },


.....}
```

**Actual Result** :

```
{
     "empty" :false
}
```

Comment: Can you please put the codes in Code tag? :)

Comment: @Pranay I have put the code in ` ` only and in the code box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Wrapper or Response class instead of the JSON object

```
public class Response{
private String code;
private String msg;
private Subject subject;
//Add getter setter here

}
```

Now in your code

```
Response res = new Response;
```

//After setting values

```
return res;
```

Also, change response type as follows

```
public Response getSubjectList(@QueryParam("user_id") long user_id){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning List, you are returning a JSONObject. 
There are 2 ways to go about it, either change the return type or change how you want to return the json object.

Comment: yes I have created a response class and return its object. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the return type of your function to JSONObject.

Comment: After changing still it was not working. But after creating a class of response. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Response](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/index.html?javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html)

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

json.put("code", 200);
json.put("message", "Success");
json.put("subject", sub);

return Response.ok().entity(json).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

create a Response class with List or your Subject class as shown below.Use List for multiple students.

```
public class Response{
private String code;
private String msg;
// private Subject subject; 
        // (OR)
 private List<Subject> subject;
// getters and setters
}
```

Your class should look like.

```
    @RestController
public class SubjectResources {

SubjectService subjectService = new SubjectService();

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getSubjectList(@QueryParam("user_id") long user_id){

List<Subject> sub = subjectService.getAllSubejcts(user_id);//checked and List sub has all details.

Response resp=new Response();
resp.setCode("--------");
resp.setMsg("-------");
resp.setSubject(sub);
return resp;
}
```

Use @RestController and configure json Converters in spring dispatcher-servlet file. You can also use @ResponseBody (google it). Whoever calls your SubjectResources class they will get Response class in the form of json. Spring will automatically convert into json.If you want to test your class use Soup UI tool.

```
<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

If you are developing for learning and want to test your class without soap ui use ObjectMapper class.Place below code in your class

```
String jsonStr="{}";
try{
ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
jsonStr=mapper.writeValueAsString(resp);
System.out.println(jsonStr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @rohan. It's very helpful.